# Table storage showing data in only string format

Tags: azure-table-storage, azure-data-factory

I'm using ADF pipeline to copy data from data lake to blob storage and then from blob storage to table storage.

[image]

As you can see below, here are the column types in ADF Data Flow Sink - Blob Storage (integer, string, timestamp):

[image]

Here is the Mapping settings in Copy data activity:

[image]

On checking the output in table storage, I see all columns are of string type:

[image]

Why is table storage saving data in string values? How do I resolve this issue in table storage so that it will accept columns in the right type (integer, string, timestamp)? Please let me know. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out the issue - I was using DelimitedText format for Blob Storage. After converting to Parquet format, I can see data being written to table storage in correct type.

Answer (score 2):

In usually, when load data from blob storage in Data Factory, **all the default data type in blob file are String**, Data Factory will help you convert the data type automatically to Sink.

But it also can not meet all our requests.

I tested copy data from Blob to Table Storage and found that: **if we don't specify the data type manually in Source, after pipeline executed, all the data type will be String in Sink(Table Storage)**.

For example, this my Source blob file:
[image]

If I don't change the source data type, it seems that everything is ok in Sink table:
[image]
[image]

But after the pipeline executed, the data type in table storage are all String:
[image]

If we change the data type in Source blob manually, and it works ok! 
[image]

[image]

For another question, a little confuse that just from you screenshot, that seems the UI of Mapping Data Flow Sink, but Mapping Data Flow doesn't support Table Storage as Sink.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! Updated my question to show how my pipeline looks like - I have a Mapping Data Flow that stores data to Blob first (question shows schema of Data Flow Sink - Blob Storage). Should I make any updates to Mapping settings in Copy data activity for table storage to accept types other than string?

Comment: @user3693060 We can't achieve that. Once the blob created in Mapping Flow, and the data type will turned to be String. The source is the output of the Data Flow, we can not change it and do mapping manually  in CopyDataFromBlobToTable active.

Comment: Hi @user3693060,hope you are doing well.  If my answer is helpful for you,  can  please mark it as answer? This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you! I need to use the following query to filter data in table:
?$filter=Age%20gt%2030"


Currently this doesn't work as the data in Age column is in string format.

Is it possible to first convert the data in 'Age' column to integer format and use the above query?

Comment: @user3693060 You're welcome. I'm sorry I haven't tried that operations before and may can't answer you.